# Replace all whitespace at all beginning line and empty lines

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like:

```
   -------beginning certificate


           2323jjjdcnnjjjsd


        sdsdsdsdsdsdsd
```

and I would like to transform it in (white spaces should be removed only at beginning of each lines):

```
-------beginning certificate
2323jjjdcnnjjjsd
sdsdsdsdsdsdsd
```

I have tried with :

```
string.replaceAll("^[\n\r\s]*","");
```

but seems nothing happens.

Comment: Remove the `^`.

Comment: I need to catch the white spaces only at beginning of string

Comment: Fyi: `\s` already contains `\r` and `\n` afaik :) Also it looks like [it works](https://regex101.com/r/LhCqgC/1). Maybe you forgot to escape backslashes in string. Try `"^\\s*"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```bash
string = string.replaceAll("(?m)^\\s+|\\h+$", "");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uDYtDD/2)

**Breakdown:**

- `(?m)`: Enable multiline mode
- `^\\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces (including line breaks) at start
- `|`: OR
- `\\h+$`: Match 1+ horizontal whitespaces before end

Comment: seems not working

Comment: Please try my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Reasons why it's not working could be that:

1. Backslash was not escaped
2. Lack of [multiline flag](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE), so [`^`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) only matches start of the string and not start of each line.

Further to mention that [`\s`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) already contains `\r` and `\n`. You should be fine using (as a Java String)

```
"^\\s+"
```

See [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dmT9Zu/1) or [Java demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##dZGxboMwEIbn8hQnJlAaD8mIGDpkiJRUldJOpZWMcaipMZZ9RKmqPDs1YKooCufhl/77znc@V/REl1Xx3XWi1o1BqJxBWhSSGF7yM9lTZF/cJMFM/oUicqOSIGCSWgubM6215PAbgAvd5lIwsEjRyakRBdRUqOiARqjy/QOoKW3s4T6OQlEJYxqGDpBC@JlldhEm9yk7isNcZjlGzkuhVG8zblAcBaPIM9WfMHiAxcBOsVqv1lVVFUwpJ7a4y9ni@szO0uYW@1GugBvSLwy013RyCGtqLSSPhmc//tv7t93rdrd93sS3Tf3fuJWOmk6XEu9E427iZG6/tpX9uB53X6olZfxJymh4yVXh4ccir0nTItGuGKWKxnLPXIJL1/0B) (compile with `MULTILINE` or use `(?m)` flag)
Note that I also changed the `*` [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) to `+` for matching *one or more* whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that will be useful. this code removes white spaces from beginning of lines and blank lines from a string

```
string.replaceAll("(?m)^[\\s&&[^\\n]]+", "").replace("(?m)^[\n]","")
```

This is the shorter form.

```
string.replaceAll("(?m)^[\\s&&[^\\n]]+|^[\n]", "")
```